# How to achieve multiple camera performance for mobile or low spec

Tags: unity-game-engine

My game scenario made it out how so I need multiple cameras with different depths and layers work with each other to output what I'm looking for.
My question is, as long as I keep geometry as low as possible, and have simple shaders with low rendering pipeline, and most importantly, giving each camera only their own objects (within their layers) to render, can I achieve a platform-free game, performance-wise? In other words, do unity cameras put some weights on the game disregarding what they're rendering?

For math enthusiasts, this is what I want to know:
I have 3 objects, A,B and C. And I have three Cameras, cA, cB and cC. So if cA only renders A, cB only renders B and cC only renders C; is this whole thing equal (or at least close) to have these three objects rendered by only one camera in performance?

Comment: I don't know but I guess each Camera adds some additional overhead so I would expect that it is better to have one Camera render everything than multiple Cameras rendering single parts. How would you handle depth and occlusion? If you have multiple Cameras they render in a fixed order so what if object C is behind object A but cC renders after cA ?

Comment: I would agree with @derHugo but want to add that this is going to be very situation-dependent, so you're not likely to get a good answer here.  Your best bet would be to try it both ways with a sample scene and use the built-in profiler to get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Every camera in Unity has a culling overhead, so the fewer cameras in a scene, the better. Consider whether Command Buffers can be used to achieve the desired effect.